# What type of SQL locks could be involved in the following queries executed inside of a TransactionScope which is ReadCommited?

Tags: c#, sql, transactions, locking, transactionscope

So we have four statements (changed for purposes of the question)

They are run inside a `TransactionScope` (`ReadCommitted`) and multiple processes could be calling the same stored procedure containing these statements at once:

```
SELECT @BathroomId = B.BathroomId
FROM Bathrooms B
WHERE B.BathroomSuite = @BathroomSuite AND B.SuiteIsAvailable = 1  
(No indexes used at all)

SELECT @OrderReceiptId = O.OrderReceiptId
FROM Order O 
WHERE O.OrderId = @OrderId 
(Clustered Index) 

IF ISNULL(@OrderReceiptId, -1) = -1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrderReceipt]
        .....
    (Clustered index on PK) 

    UPDATE Order 
    SET OrderReceiptId = @@SCOPE_IDENTITY
    WHERE OrderId = @OrderId
```

From my limited reading, I understand that only row locks should be used for the SELECTS (therefore, limiting the impact on contention on these tables)

But, then, what lock(s) would be used for the INSERT/UPDATE and then what impact does this have on other processes vying with the overarching transaction?

Are we effectively gating these tables until the transaction has completed? Or just some of the tables (I.e. just the INSERT and the UPDATE - owing to the fact that the transaction is really only related to the INSERT and UPDATE in my mind (can't rollback a SELECT for example)

Are other contending processes going to have to wait until the transaction completes (which is certainly not unreasonable I think)

The database locking and transaction relationship is somewhat fuzzy as is then how this affects multiple callers of the stored procedure containing these statements.

N.B. Please ignore dodgy relationship between Order and OrderReceipt, it is definitely sub-optimal.

I think I am conflating Transaction as a locking mechanism (sort of like a thread lock used for thread synchronisation) and database level locking

**EDIT**: Yes I am conflating Transaction and DB locking (used together but slightly different responsibilities), any google 101 site tells me this. It's embarrassing but it will teach me for not having a mooch first.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? If SQL Server, the answer might depend on your snapshot isolation level...

Comment: @OlaBerntsson SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple process calling the same SP,there will be no contention or locking,blocking ..

Your select takes a shared lock in the isolation level you are  in and the lock will be released as soon as the row as read

But you might see locking ,blocking if there are some update processes or delete processes which try to access the table at the same time..

You could also use this [traceflag to see all the locks taken](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/138863/31995) ..This trace flag will write the locks taken in order to messages tab

```
DBCC TRACEON(1200,3604,-1);
SELECT ....
DBCC TRACEOFF(1200,3604,-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server this probably depends on your snapshot isolation level.

Inserting something into the clustered index will lock the whole table, as far as I know. In other words, the first insert will block all other inserts until completed. Reading (SELECT) is a different story:

Check the properties/options of the database, look for "Is read committed snapshot on". If this setting is True, concurrent processes can **read** while you are holding that insert transaction. If not - all other reads will be blocked until the transaction is completed.

Note that turning this option on might affect the db performance in some scenarios, though I've personally not had any real issues with it.